# Flask-login causing login form to not validate

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

The login form of my flask app is failing to validate (form.valididate = false) when the app has automatically logged users out:

```
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

form.errors returns an empty dictionary {}.

Any ideas what is going on?

Login route below. When the user has been automatically logged out the code beneath 'if form.validate_on_submit...' is completely bypassed.

```
@view.route('/Login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_suspended != True:
        return redirect(url_for('view.Index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('view.login'))

        if user.is_suspended and user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Your login has been suspended. Please contact NZGBC.')
            return redirect(url_for('view.login'))

        user.session_token = user.generate_session_token()
        db.session.commit()

        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)

        if form.remember_me.data is not True:
            app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=60)
        else:
            app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=365)
        
        next = request.args.get('next')
        # is_safe_url should check if the url is safe for redirects.
        # See http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/62/ for an example.
        if not is_safe_url(next):
            return abort(400)

        return redirect(next or url_for('view.Index'))

    return render_template('login.html', highlight='11', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Comment: Please provide more info, like the login route and more dependant settings if available.

Comment: @SLDem, login route added.

Comment: you need to check the condition before the form validation if your user is authenticated and try to debug the code pausing at every line in the view

Comment: Also can you explain your problem a little bit better, meaning the steps you've took for it to appear.

Comment: @SLDem, I was testing the timeout function. Set the timeout to 5 seconds. Weirdly, when I set this to 10 seconds the problem disappears. Realised that the form IS returning a error - it says the CSRF tokens do not match. Why would they not match with a 5 second timeout, but do match with a 10 second timeout?

Comment: could be that the token is taking too long to create, can you share the timeout function?

Comment: @SLDem, the timeout function is embedded in the login route as posted above.

Comment: so you mean if your user is auto logged out and then he clicks `Login` the code after `if form.validate...` stops working?

Comment: @SLDem, correct. The form does not validate, and it appears this is because the CSRF tokens no longer match. Can't understand how this could happen, since presumably when Flask redirects to the login route after auto logout, it would generate a new (matching) CSRF token on the login form and in the session. Thanks for your help BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

Obliously after using the `CSRF` token for submitting a form it will fail, since `CSRF` tokens are 1-time use.

Try doing this as a workaround in your **login** route:

```
try:
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    # ... process your form normally ...
except:
    return redirect(url_for('view.login'))
    # ... maybe display a message for the user to reenter his creds because he was logged out ...
```

This should work as a viable fix for your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. If a user has been redirected to the login page because he/she has been automatically logged out, the login page would be freshly delivered from the server so the CSRF token should be newly created.

Comment: if there is any error during submitting the login form it will redirect the user back the login page with a new `CSRF` token and let them login